# How to avoid extra digit being added in the addition of decimals in Python

Tags: python

`print(37.4<(32.0+5.0+0.2+0.2))`
This statement gives a True result but I need it should give me a False as the addition of the numbers (32.0+5.0+0.2+0.2) is precisely the same as 37.4 but here it gives the following result 37.400000000000006 for this equation (32.0+5.0+0.2+0.2). Hence, I am getting a True result rather False one.

I am new to python so don't know how to deal with it.

Many thanks

Comment: `(32.0+5.0+0.2+0.2)` indeed results in `37.400000000000006` in many programming languages. Even `0.1+0.2` results in `0.30000000000000004`. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken . And this site shows the behaviors of many different programming languages: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: In this case, you could also multiply with 10 and compare the int values.

Comment: Plenty of Python solutions presented in answers to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the function round(number, ndigits)

Comment: You can see this print(37.4<round((32.0+5.0+0.2+0.2),1)) is False

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [decimals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal("37.4") < Decimal("32.0") + Decimal("5.0") + Decimal("0.2") + Decimal("0.2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use round().

For example, if you want to round the number to 2 digits, do this:

```
round((32.0+5.0+0.2+0.2), 2)
```

And to answer your issue:

```
print(37.4<round((32.0+5.0+0.2+0.2), 2))
```